# google sheet: Log Sheet Data Retrieval based on Dates (from and to)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried this below Query formula but I got error #VALUE! I checked all possible errors. but still, I am not able to get the result.

in Cell A2
=QUERY(Log!B:J, "select J,L,P,S where B = '"&A1&"' and J >= date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)

I have a "Log" Sheet containing data on the Daily Attendance of the Employees,
Date (dd/mm/yyyy) in J2:J100

Employee code in B2:B100

ClockIn in L2:L100

ClockOut in P2:P100 and

Location in S2:S100. Now,

In the "Payroll" sheet, I will enter one Employee Code in A1,

in C1 I will enter the "from" date, and

in D1 "To" date.

Based on A1, C1, and D1 references,

I need the values from the "Log" sheet to the "Payroll" Sheet following from A2.

A2=Log!J2:J100, B2=L2:L100, C2=P2:P100, D2=S2:S100 based on from and to date specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the entire column range `L,P,S` in data part `=QUERY(Log!B:J`

Try: =QUERY(`Log!B:S`, "select J,L,P,S where B = '"&A1&"' and J >= date '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.  I am getting the values, But please help me out it should also based on criteria that matches A1 value

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output (manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: maybe try `B = "&A1&" and` in place of `B = '"&A1&"' and` if and only employee codes are numericals

Comment: thanks :) still gives #REF! error
here is the link to my sample sheet -  please help me out
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmGJaVnSNxSjdRds3k6Rid0Oglhtr0OmF6xNvu6RiJM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you can try either `=filter({Log!J:K,Log!L:L,Log!O:P,Log!S:S},Log!B:B=A2,Log!J:J>=C2,Log!J:J<=D2)` OR `=QUERY(Log!B:S, "select J,K,L,O,P,S where B = "&A2&" and J >= date '"&TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(D2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)`

Comment: Both Filter and Query are working. Thank you so much. works exactly what I need. :) star star